# Java How to Extract a Double from a String from a text File

Tags: java.util.scanner

My Java assignment is to to write a Java application that uses data from a text file with earth quake information and generate a report with:

> the count of the number of values read,
>
> the total sum of the magnitudes,
>
> the average magnitude value (to 2 decimal places),
>
> the maximum magnitude value, where it happened and when
>
> the minimum magnitude value, where it happened and when

I can get the file to open using File and Scanner classes but I can't get it to read extract only a double (i.e the magnitudes below: 1.6, 1.8, ect.). I can get it to count the number of lines. I've tried deliminators with the Scanner and Pattern classes and then using Double parse but it won;t work. I'm a rookie for sure and this class just took a leap.

Example of input from text file:

```
1.6,"Southern California","Wednesday, January 18, 2012 19:19:12 UTC"
1.8,"Southern California","Wednesday, January 18, 2012 19:03:00 UTC"
1.8,"Southern California","Wednesday, January 18, 2012 18:46:53 UTC"
4.7,"Bonin Islands, Japan region","Wednesday, January 18, 2012 18:20:40 UTC"
1.6,"Southern California","Wednesday, January 18, 2012 17:58:07 UTC"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Would you please post your code and show what error you're getting when you "can't get it to extarct only a double"?

Comment: isn't it Double.valueof(string). would need more to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
String str = "1.6,california,wednesday,whatever";
String[] results = str.split(",");
Double testDouble = Double.valueOf(str[0]);
```